# Forwarding ncurses key events to an X11 window

Tags: c++, c, x11, ncurses, qemu

My application's user interface consists of two windows: the console (handled by `ncurses`) and an X11 window for graphics. I would like to handle key events in a centralized way. That is, no matter which of the two windows is active, the same event loop should handle all the key events. I already have an event loop for X11 events. All that remains to be done is to forward all the console events to the X11 window.

The main building block to achieve this forwarding is found [here](http://www.doctort.org/adam/nerd-notes/x11-fake-keypress-event.html). The only other thing I need is to be able to translate from the value returned by `getch()` to X11 `keycode`. After about four hours of searching the web, I found [this](https://github.com/agocke/qemu/blob/master/curses_keys.h) code, which is part of [qemu](http://wiki.qemu.org/). However, when I compare the mapping it provides with the output of `xev`, the two do not match. For example, for the `Home` key, `xev` gives 110, while the mentioned mapping gives 71 | 0x0100, which is 327. Are these two different kinds of `keycodes`? What am I missing?

Comment: The two are unrelated (except for the trivial case where the POSIX character set happens to be used).

Comment: @ThomasDickey Are you aware of any existing mapping that I can re-use?

Comment: Not offhand: you could construct a mapping from curses special keys to X special keys, but I do not recall seeing a reusable table for this purpose.

Comment: That's an awful way to achieve device independence. An arguably better way is to define your own abstract event system and map both X11 events and ncurses keypresses to it.

Comment: In any case keycodes are not portable. You can map ncurses keys to X11 keysyms and then translate keysyms to keycodes at run time, but I would very much recommend the method described in the previos comment instead.

Comment: X11 keycodes essentially denote "what key was pressed", by position. What you see in ncurses are (essentially) "one or more keys were pressed, this is the sequence of characters that were produced" (the Home key would be "ESC O H" (that's the sequence of one escape character, capital O capital H), if your terminal happens to be a VT100 descendent.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, mixing application frameworks is, almost by definition, difficult.

I think the best way to achieve what you want is to have two separate processes or threads, one for the console and the other for the X11 application. In each you would have the relevant event loop handler. To join them together use an IPC channel, either a pipe or socket. You should be able to make the socket/pipe an input to the X11 event loop handler with its own callback. You can have a select() on the console side waiting on the socket or STDIN; this allows you to call getch() when there's a keypress ready or read from the socket when the X11 has sent something through the socket. If you used something like ZeroMQ in place of the socket, even better.

So, what would you send through the socket? You would have to define your own event structure to pass between the console and the X11 application. Each side would populate and dispatch one of these when it needs to send something to the other. The types of event you'd need to describe would include would be things like quit, keypress (+ keypress data), etc.

Most likely you'd arrange the X11 end so that the socket reading callback read the structure from the socket, interpreted it and decided what callback should then be called directly. If your key presses are only for selecting menu entries, buttons, etc then this might be a not-too-bad (but not brilliant)  way of avoiding the mapping problem.

This does mean having two event loop handlers, a socket and two processes/threads. But it does avoid blending the two into a single thing. It also means your console could be on a completely different machine! If you had used zeromq you could easily have multiple consoles connected to the X11 application in a PUSH/PULL configuration; perhaps absurd, but possible.